# Is it OK to use "semantically reversed" associations, like Message blongsTo Attachment, in CakePHP?

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling, associations, erd

Suppose that we have the following partial ER diagram:

[image: An ER diagram with 5 entities: messages, submissions, attachments, assignments, and lectures]

Notice that the `attachments` table will subsequently be used for the messages', submissions', assignments', and lectures' attachments.

The problem is with the 3 one-to-one relationships between `attachments` and `messages`, `submissions`, and `assignments`. According to CakePHP's conventions, `Message belongsTo Attachment` (and `Attachment hasOne Message`) because `Message` contains the foreign key (the same thing applies to the other 2 relationships). Of course, it makes more sense to say that `Message hasOne Attachment` (and that `Attachment belongsTo Message`). If we only had `messages` and `attachments`, it would be easy to "*properly orient*" the relationship by moving the foreign key to `attachments`.

But the problem again is that `messages`, `submissions`, `assignments`, and `lectures` have relationships with the same `attachments` table. One way to get the "*semantically correct*" relationships is to have 4 different `Attachment` models: `MessageAttachment`, `SubmissionAttachment`, `AssignmentAttachment`, and `LectureAttachment`.

Assuming we are only interested in retrieving the attachment of a certain message, submission, or assignment, **is it OK to use these *semantically reversed* associations, or should we *properly orient* them by separating `Attachment` into 4 different models as mentioned above?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By semantics you also mean the natural semantics of the language. But you are talking about a particular, technical scenario that holds a different semantics.

That's perfectly fine. These are just names. If you have A and B (attachments and messages), and in your case B hasOne A, then it **is** the right thing to say attachment hasOne message.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this answer is a bit along the lines of "you should be able to do this with an MVC framework".  I am unfamiliar with CakePHP, and briefly looking at the documentation I can't figure out how to actually do the following.

In Perl DBIx::Class (which I am familiar with) it is possible to impose additional constraints in `belongs to` relationships than just fk matching.  I would solve this problem by adding a field `type` to `attachment`, which indicates the type of object (e.g., `message`, `lecture`) that owns this particular `attachment` and then give `attachment` a `foreign_id`.

The query syntax would be `SELECT * from attachment WHERE foreign_id == myId AND type == MyType`.

It looks like that structure would let you eliminate the `attachments_lectures` table, since that seems to just be letting you have many attachments per lecture.  You would also get for free being able to have many attachments for assignments, submissions, and messages if you were so inclined.